# Ruby LittleLexer

Tags: ruby, lexical-analysis

I'm wondering if Ruby's LittleLexer project might have been renamed or moved?

Following the link below doesn't seem to work any longer.

http://rubyforge.org/projects/littlelexer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like RubyForge, a site that hosted many projects, has been shut down.  I could not find the source on rubygems.org or archive.org.  Looks like the last version of the project is from 2004.  If you go to http://littlelexer.rubyforge.org and view the source of that page, there is an email address for the maintainer of littlelexer at the bottom.  You could try emailing that person.